# 'Play' & 'Java' are not recognized as an internal or external command even after adding env variable

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, environment-variables

Hi I am new to play framework and i am trying to set it up. When I go to the directory the play.bat file and execute any play commands they are getting executed but not from any other directory.

I have added both the play path and the java path to my environment variables.

I was just checking if I can execute a java command from elsewhere but I couldn't. `Java -version` threw an error that java is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: Can somebody please reply ASAP!

Comment: After setting the env var, open *new* command shell and then try.

Comment: Yes I did. Still dint work

Comment: what is the path used? It should be to `bin` folder.

Comment: This is the path I have set - C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8\bin

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've setup my Java and play framework on my windows machine.

- Setup Java Home : Set the environment variable JAVA_HOME to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51"
- Setup a variable called PLAY_INSTALL_DIR. I have multiple versions of play and I've extracted them all to this directory. I've set it to "C:\Bin\play-framework" . Inside this directory different sub-directories such as "play-2.2.2", "play-2.0.4" and so on
- Setup a variable called PLAY_CURRENT to indicate which play installation has to be used. For the moment it is "play-2.2.2"
- Finally plug them all into your path variable like so %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PLAY_INSTALL_DIR%\%PLAY_CURRENT%

When you have newer play versions available, you can put them in the same directory as PLAY_INSTALL and then just change the PLAY_CURRENT value.